# Kibana dashboards and Visualizations missing

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I'm new to ELK. I installed Elasticsearch 1.7.1., logstash and Kibana 4. I was using it for a week and generated few graphs and dashboards and saved everything. All of a sudden all the graphs(visualizations) and dashboards went missing. Now Kibana shows no saved dashboards/visualization available. Please guide me on how to get back the saved graphs and dashboards.

Comment: Sounds like someone deleted your .kibana index.

Comment: That is not possible, only i have access to the server. No one else has used it except me. All the dashboards and visualizations went missing after rebooting.

Comment: I'm able to see .kibana directory inside elasticsearch directory. It contains two directories namely "0" and "_state". but still Kibana shows 0 dashboards and 0 visualization.

Comment: Same here. Suddenly all of kibana configuration vanished